# How can I create a list which contains all the replies to a specific tweet using tweepy?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, tweets

I am not sure why, but tweepy has no direct method that allows you to access the all the replies to a specific tweet. I want to store replies to a tweet in an list called replies.

I have looked every where online for a solution, however none of the given solutions seem to work or they are out of date.

I have been using the below code which I found from another user on Stack overflow.

It should fetch 10 recent tweets of an user(name) along with the replies to that particular tweet.The replies will be saved on to a list named replies. You can retrieve more tweets by increasing the items count (eg:items(100)).

It is capturing and printing the main tweets, however the replies list is always being returned empty and no replies are being printed.

I would greatly appreciate any help, Thanks!

```
replies=[] 

non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)  
for full_tweets in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,screen_name=name,timeout=999999).items(10):
  for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q='to:'+name,result_type='recent',timeout=999999).items(1000):
    if hasattr(tweet, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str'):
      if (tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str==full_tweets.id_str):
        replies.append(tweet.text)
  print("Tweet :",full_tweets.text.translate(non_bmp_map))
  for elements in replies:
       print("Replies :",elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tweet_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
replies=[]
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q='to:'+name, result_type='recent', timeout=999999).items(1000):
    if hasattr(tweet, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str'):
        if (tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str==tweet_id):
            replies.append(tweet)

with open('xxx', 'w') as f:
csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=('replies'))
csv_writer.writeheader()
for tweet in replies:
    row = {'replies': tweet.text.replace('\n',' ')}
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good practice. Please consider [Explaining how this answers the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)